# Is it possible in Twig to set autoescape strategy in the layout file

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a layout file that has a `{% block content %}{% endblock %}` inside a Javascript array like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    cols:[
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        ];
</script>
```

And then is extended like this in the many templates that use the layout file like this (the real templates have many more lines of code and variables):

```
{% block content %}
    { view:"text", name:"visitDate", value:"{{ date }}", label:"Date/Time:", labelWidth:100, width:285, labelAlign:"right", readonly:true },
{% endblock %}
```

As the `content` block will always need to be escaped using the "js" strategy is there any way to specify this in the layout template I've tired:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    cols:[
            {% autoescape 'js' %}
                {% block content %}{% endblock %}
            {% endautoescape %} 
        ];
</script>
```

But that doesn't seem to work, and can't find any examples in the Twig documentation. I can get it to work if I add the `autoescape` block inside the `content` block in the templates, but this doesn't feel like the correct way to do this.

As an example, using the above code the following HTML/Javascript should be sent to the browser where `{{ date }}` = "17/12/2017 15:01:53":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    cols:[
            { view:"text", name:"visitDate", value:"17\x2F12\x2F2017\x2015\x3A01\x3A53", label:"Date/Time:", labelWidth:100, width:285, labelAlign:"right", readonly:true },
        ];
</script>
```

Only the template variables in the child templates `content` block should be escaped not the actual Javascript code which is what you get if you use something along the lines of `{{ block('content')|e('js') }}`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of is to create node visitor class, that will process every twig node and depending on the block's name it will apply corresponding escape strategy.

1. First of all [create custom twig extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html)
2. Create node visitor object which will apply escape strategy to every node between opening and closing `content` blocks
3. Register node vistor in the extension.

Here is an example visitor that will aplly `js` escape filter on every `print` node inside `content` block:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Twig;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getNodeVisitors()
    {
        /**
         * Node visitor that applies `js` escaping strategy to every output node under `content` block
         *
         * @var \Twig_NodeVisitorInterface
         */
        $visitor = new class() implements \Twig_NodeVisitorInterface {
            /**
             * @var bool
             */
            private $escape = false;

            /**
             * {@inheritdoc}
             */
            public function enterNode(\Twig_Node $node, \Twig_Environment $env)
            {
                // Start of `content` block found, set `escape` to true to indicate that next nodes should be escaped
                if ($this->isContentBlockNode($node)) {
                    $this->escape = true;
                }

                return $node;
            }

            /**
             * {@inheritdoc}
             */
            public function leaveNode(\Twig_Node $node, \Twig_Environment $env)
            {
                if ($node instanceof \Twig_Node_Module) {
                    $this->escape = false;
                }

                if ($this->escape) {
                    if ($node instanceof \Twig_Node_Print) {
                        $expr = $node->getNode('expr');
                        // Skipping if escape strategy provided in the template for this node
                        if ($expr instanceof \Twig_Node_Expression_Filter) {
                            return $node;
                        }

                        $line = $expr->getTemplateLine();
                        $name = new \Twig_Node_Expression_Constant('escape', $line);
                        $args = new \Twig_Node(array(new \Twig_Node_Expression_Constant('js', $line), new \Twig_Node_Expression_Constant(null, $line), new \Twig_Node_Expression_Constant(true, $line)));

                        $filter = new \Twig_Node_Expression_Filter($expr, $name, $args, $line);

                        $class = get_class($node);

                        return new $class($filter, $node->getTemplateLine());
                    }
                }

                // End of `content` block, disable escape policy for further nodes
                if ($this->isContentBlockNode($node)) {
                    $this->escape = false;
                }

                return $node;
            }

            /**
             * {@inheritdoc}
             */
            public function getPriority()
            {
                return -10;
            }

            /**
             * Checks whether the node is `content` block
             *
             * @param \Twig_Node $node
             *
             * @return bool
             */
            private function isContentBlockNode(\Twig_Node $node): bool
            {
                return ($node instanceof \Twig_Node_Block && 'content' === $node->getAttribute('name'));
            }
        };

        return [$visitor];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to escape all of the blocks content, just the variables being output in the block.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. I have updated my answer